# How do a linq join of an object to itself?

Tags: linq, join, self

In the code below I'm trying to join an object to itself. The join kinda works, but it's giving me 4 rows instead of the expected 1 row with both values in the same new object and not 4 copies of the same object. Thanks!!

```
  var values = rptDataPkg.Datasets.Item(0).Result.AsEnumerable()
 .Where(f => f.Field<int>("RowType") == 3 && 
             f.Field<int>("Category") == 1 && 
           ((f.Field<int>("ItemID") == -1000) || (f.Field<int>("ItemID") == -1001)))
.Select(f => new
{    
   joinOn = 1,
   Proc = f.Field<string>("Item"),
   fieldVal = Convert.ToDecimal(f.Field<decimal?>(field))
}).ToList();

var join = values.Join(values, b1 => b1.joinOn, b2 => b2.joinOn, 
           (b1, b2) => new
            {
                inHVal = b1.fieldVal,
                offSVal = b2.fieldVal
            });
```

Comment: -1.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Isn't there a simpler way to do that than to bring Linq and Join into the picture?  It seems you are cross joining 2 things (-1000 and -1001) to themselves, winding up with 4 matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your `values` list has two entries. Both will have a `joinOn` value of 1, so you'll end up with both rows matching themselves and each other. So if the rows are A and B, you'll have

```
(A, A)
(A, B)
(B, A)
(B, B)
```

Comment: Right! I've been trying to add Linq to everything lately and sometimes it's just not necessary.

Comment: I recently discovered the awesomeness of linq and lambdas and often similarly try to use it for things that are more straightforward without it.  It's key to remember that normal loops are generally faster.

Comment: @Oofpez: No, it's key to remember that normally the speed difference is irrelevant, but readability is important.